# android studio java- automatic appointments barber studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my activity for reserving date and appointments

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            selectedDate = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d_%02d_%04d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1, year);
            terminAdapter.clearReservations();

            terminAdapter.clearColors();
        }
    });

    terminiReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("termini");
    recyclerViewTermini = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTermini);

    List<TerminModel> terminiList = generateTermini("termini");
    terminAdapter = new TerminAdapter(terminiList);

    recyclerViewTermini.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    recyclerViewTermini.setAdapter(terminAdapter);

    terminAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

    datePicker.init(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            selectedDate = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d_%02d_%04d", dayOfMonth, monthOfYear + 1, year);

            terminAdapter.clearColors(); // Clear reserved status and update UI
        }
    });

    terminAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new TerminAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String selectedTermin) {
            if (selectedDate != null) {
                try {
                    // Format the selected date
                    SimpleDateFormat inputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                    SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

                    Date parsedSelectedDate = inputDateFormat.parse(selectedDate);
                    String formattedSelectedDate = outputDateFormat.format(parsedSelectedDate);


                    String keyToCheck = "korisnik:" + loggedInUsername + "_frizer:" + imePrezime +
                             "_termin:" + selectedTermin + "__" + formattedSelectedDate;

                    // Query the database to check if the key exists
                    terminiReference.child(keyToCheck).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                // The time slot is already reserved, show a message to the user
                                Toast.makeText(VrijemeDatumUslugeActivity.this, "Odabrani termin nije slobodan!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // The time slot is available, proceed with reservation
                                // Continue with your existing code for saving the reservation in the database and navigating to the next activity
                                try {

                                    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                                    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

                                    Date parsedDate = inputFormat.parse(selectedTermin);
                                    String formattedTermin = outputFormat.format(parsedDate);

                                    // Postavljanje ključa (naziva) termina na formatirani termin
                                    String key = "korisnik:" + loggedInUsername + "_frizer:" + imePrezime +
                                           "_termin:" + formattedTermin + "__" + formattedSelectedDate;

                                    TerminFirebaseModel terminFirebaseModel = new TerminFirebaseModel(selectedDate, formattedTermin, imeUsluge, loggedInUsername, imePrezime);
                                    terminiReference.child(key).setValue(terminFirebaseModel);

                                   

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(VrijemeDatumUslugeActivity.this, "Greška pri provjeri dostupnosti termina.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(VrijemeDatumUslugeActivity.this, "Odaberite datum prije spremanja termina!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int postaviBojuTermina(String vrijeme) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}

private void provjeriRezervacije() {
    terminiReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot terminSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                TerminFirebaseModel rezerviraniTermin = terminSnapshot.getValue(TerminFirebaseModel.class);
                if (rezerviraniTermin != null) {
                    String rezerviranoVrijeme = rezerviraniTermin.getSelectedTermin();
                    promijeniBojuTermina(rezerviranoVrijeme);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(VrijemeDatumUslugeActivity.this, "Greška pri dohvaćanju podataka iz baze.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
private List<TerminModel> generateTermini(String selectedDate) {
    List<TerminModel> terminiList = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        String startTime = timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        // Check if the current time slot is reserved
        boolean isReserved = checkReservationStatus(startTime, selectedDate);

        TerminModel terminModel = new TerminModel(startTime, selectedDate);
        terminModel.setReserved(isReserved);
        terminiList.add(terminModel);

        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    }

    return terminiList;
}

private boolean checkReservationStatus(String selectedTermin, String selectedDate) {
   

    String keyToCheck = "frizer:" + imePrezime + "_termin:" + selectedTermin + "__" + selectedDate;
    return isTerminReservedInDatabase(keyToCheck);
}
private boolean isTerminReservedInDatabase(String keyToCheck) {
    final boolean[] isReserved = {false}; // Using an array to store the result as it needs to be final for the listener

    terminiReference.child(keyToCheck).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            isReserved[0] = snapshot.exists();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });

    return isReserved[0];
}
private void promijeniBojuTermina(String rezerviranoVrijeme) {
    terminAdapter.promijeniBojuTermina(rezerviranoVrijeme);
}
```

}

```
public class TerminAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TerminAdapter.TerminViewHolder> {

    private final List<TerminModel> terminiList;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String selectedTermin);

        int postaviBojuTermina(String vrijeme);
    }

    public TerminAdapter(List<TerminModel> terminiList) {
        this.terminiList = terminiList;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TerminViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_termin, parent, false);
        return new TerminViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TerminViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final TerminModel termin = terminiList.get(position);

        holder.textViewVrijeme.setText(termin.getVrijeme());
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(termin.isReserved() ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
        int backgroundColor = termin.isReserved() ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN;
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int clickedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

                if (clickedPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (!termin.isReserved() && onItemClickListener != null) {
                        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(termin.getVrijeme());
                        termin.setReserved(true);
                        notifyItemChanged(clickedPosition);
                    } else {
                        // Handle reserved termin click
                        // You can show a message or perform some other action
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return terminiList.size();
    }

    public void promijeniBojuTermina(String rezerviranoVrijeme) {
        for (int i = 0; i < terminiList.size(); i++) {
            if (terminiList.get(i).getVrijeme().equals(rezerviranoVrijeme)) {
                notifyItemChanged(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public String getItemAtPosition(int position) {
        return terminiList.get(position).getVrijeme();
    }
    public void clearReservations() {
        for (TerminModel termin : terminiList) {
            termin.setReserved(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void updateAvailability(int position, boolean isAvailable) {
        terminiList.get(position).setReserved(!isAvailable);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
    public void clearColors() {
        for (TerminModel termin : terminiList) {
            termin.setReserved(false);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter that the dataset has changed
    }
    static class TerminViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewVrijeme;

        public TerminViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewVrijeme = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVrijeme);
        }
    }
}
```

The current situation is when I click on a date, it checks whether it is available in firebase and only then colors it in red if it is not available.

I would like to make it a way to immediately open the activity. That is, when the changed date checks whether it is automatically available, and that I can immediately see which is available and which is not.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).